# Good way to flatten a multiple file python program for distribution?

Tags: python, distribution

I am writing a console application in python that will consist of a handful of modules, each with a couple hundred lines of code.

For development it would be nice to modularize the program, but for distribution I like the idea of being able to post the program as a single python script.

Are there any good scripts out there for flattening multiple python modules?

I know that eventually I should brave the complicated mess that is setuptools, dpkg, etc... but I'm not ready to invest that effort yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code to do this seems to exist.

Answer (score 4):

A zipfile (with just the `.pyc` or `.pyo` files in it, ideally) would suffice, especially if you're distributing code supporting a specific `X.Y` version of Python (any Z in `X.Y.Z` will do, i.e., if you support Python 2.6, that will work in 2.6.1, 2.6.2, and so on).  Just make the zipfile part of the PYTHONPATH, just *as if* it was a directory, and you're good to go.

If you support many different Python versions (in the `X.Y` sense) you can make a zipfile per version, it's still pretty simple.

Comment: That gets it down to two files, right? The main `.py` file, and an accompanying `.zip`.

Comment: Just the zip could suffice in today's python -- you can zip the main script too, and run it with Python's `-m` commandline switch. A zipfile also accepts an arbitrary prefix that could be your main script, so you'd run with just `python thezipfile.zip` -- the prefix would then be also responsible for adding the zipfile to sys.path before moving on to the "main script proper" execution.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: You're advocating not distributing the source??

Comment: @John, you can stash the sources there too, if you insist (a separate source distribution would probably be better: smaller zips &c), just put them in a "subdir" inside the zipfile that's outside of the import path so they don't interfere with runtime imports.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: The size of compressed source last bothered me when I was downloading from an RCPM at 300 bps using an acoustically-coupled modem i.e. not very recently. What is a bother to a package developer is users sending in tracebacks that don't include the source lines.

Comment: @John, I prefer to arrange my own "traceback dumps" (_with_ crucial saving, at least partial, of values of args, local variables, &c) in compressed form so they're small and the users will gladly send them to me -- the source lines in the traceback dump would just uselessly take up space (compared to just filenames and line numbers) and would be no real help to me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, but none of these really do what I was asking for, and I was already aware of the zip file option.  

I'm looking for something that will parse my top-level script and substitute the import statements with the actual imported files in a (at least moderately) python safe way.

Comment: @Drew, such code would be pretty nightmarish to write with any modicum of generality (rewriting every toplevel name to skirt around possible clashes, for starters -- and how do you deal with attempts of dynamic access to such names...?), considering the very dubious advantages (if any) that it could offer over a zipfile. Thus I doubt anybody embarked on such a herculean undertaking with dubious (if any) returns.